# Delphi HTTPRIO: Error after soap request with certificate signed

Tags: delphi, ssl, soap, x509certificate

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out what is goint wrong.

I got this message:

```
    Debugger Exception Notification
    Project Project9.exe raised exception class ERemotableException with message 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: node
at System.Xml.XmlNodeReader..ctor(XmlNode node)
at Serpro.Sped.eFinanceira.WsInternet.WsRecepcao.ReceberLoteEvento(XmlDocument loteEventos)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---'.
Break Continue Help
```

after import my Wsdl this my btn click event.

```
procedure TForm7.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
 vWsRecepcaoSoap : WsRecepcaoSoap;
 vXmlData : loteEventos;
 vHTTPRIO : THTTPRIO;
 begin
 vHTTPRIO := THTTPRIO.Create( Nil );
 vHTTPRIO.WSDLLocation := 'http://www1.receita.fazenda.gov.br/sistemas/e-financeira/documentos/doc-download/WsRecepcao.wsdl';
 vHTTPRIO.Service := 'WsRecepcao';
 vHTTPRIO.Port := 'WsRecepcaoSoap12';
 vHTTPRIO.HTTPWebNode.OnBeforePost := HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost;
 //vHTTPRIO.OnBeforeExecute := HTTPRIO1BeforeExecute;
 vWsRecepcaoSoap := vHTTPRIO as WsRecepcaoSoap;
 vXmlData := TXMLData.Create;
 vXmlData.LoadFromXML(
 //'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> '+
 '<eFinanceira xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" '+
 'xmlns="http://www.eFinanceira.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_0_1">'+
 ' <loteEventos>'+
 '  <evento id="ID0">'+
 '  <eFinanceira xmlns="http://www.eFinanceira.gov.br/schemas/evtAberturaeFinanceira/v1_0_0">'+
 '  <evtCadDeclarante id="ID00000001762">'+
 '  <ideEvento>'+
 '  <indRetificacao>1</indRetificacao>'+
 ' <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>'+
 '  <aplicEmi>2</aplicEmi>'+
 '  <verAplic>00000000000000000707</verAplic>'+
 '  </ideEvento>'+
 '  <ideDeclarante>'+
 '  <cnpjDeclarante>02475222000196</cnpjDeclarante>'+
 '  </ideDeclarante>'+
 '  <infoCadastro>'+
 '  <nome>CECM SERV ESTAT ADM DIRETA EST E SANTO</nome>'+
 '  <enderecoLivre>AV JOAO BATISTA PARRA N 673 EDF ENSEADA TOWER LJ 1 PRAIA DO SUA</enderecoLivre>'+
 '  <municipio>3205309</municipio>'+
 '  <UF>ES</UF>'+
 '  <Pais>BR</Pais>'+
 '  <paisResidencia>BR</paisResidencia>'+
 '  </infoCadastro>'+
 '  </evtCadDeclarante>'+
 '  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">'+
 '  <SignedInfo>'+
 '  <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>'+
 '  <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>'+
 '  <Reference URI="#ID00000001762">'+
 '  <Transforms>'+
 '  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>'+
 '  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>'+
 '  </Transforms>'+
 ' <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>'+
 '  <DigestValue>G8kSjLVludtkatDuCm2rLszM7D4=</DigestValue>'+
 '  </Reference>'+
 '  </SignedInfo>'+
 '  <SignatureValue>f7OmvLKjuuRQiX+6tgqBYxB5zBFgxjXMyXOqZkWtLhgW2lP/ZzM7xrnt9HZFBSetIhJNGuPhKysZzf4hZClW1YSEfi2WECb3CNzBCfjzeOA2fEJ/FJXdYdDsAvtzjTbt'+
 'E+MqrJW/u9sGNJHJDTtVfdjPwt3Y9NUJJ0SADvDtXPiow71rcpAeg3fQD3IIFlPLyz0WbGiUyzDcsl3pb7L7AYilj5Pm5utV0COq8A0jwnMylKolGHScXgJaPW3U9qHw9KDeaGP0NfgEYyYTk/C8T'+
 'NSZXb5AKj2sFr9rfLRuTOqEJHjKvlYmWsGUCTwEVkkNakTYbuNFYsXB++nVVaoD7Q==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509Certificate>MIIHQjCCBSqgAwIBAgIEAMtJKTANB'+
 'gkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBiTELMAkGA1UEBhMCQlIxEzARBgNVBAoTCklDUC1CcmFzaWwxNjA0BgNVBAsTLVNlY3JldGFyaWEgZGEgUmVjZWl0YSBGZWRlcmFsIGRvIEJyYXNpbCAtIFJGQjEtMCsGA1'+
 'UEAxMkQXV0b3JpZGFkZSBDZXJ0aWZpY2Fkb3JhIFNFUlBST1JGQnY0MB4XDTE1MDgxNDE2NTg0MVoXDTE4MDgxMzE2NTg0MVowgbYxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkJSMRMwEQYDVQQKEwpJQ1AtQnJhc2lsMTY'+
 'wNAYDVQQLEy1TZWNyZXRhcmlhIGRhIFJlY2VpdGEgRmVkZXJhbCBkbyBCcmFzaWwgLSBSRkIxEzARBgNVBAsTCkFSQ09SUkVJT1MxFTATBgNVBAsTDFJGQiBlLUNQRiBBMzEuMCwGA1UEAxMlQ0FS'+
 'TE9TIFJPR0VSSU8gRE9TIFNBTlRPUzowMjQ1MjIwNzcxMzCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADggEPADCCAQoCggEBAKpkYV/6tAjFMopRahCMbKuaoygH+NjBmIR7p5JYm2rdw0c1Vft4i2cZjSNs/'+
 'cVJsadZgxiw3YFYqIyyg+dMA78qTWpidVr4n2BOCwh7xmqjZ/t+Cf2ay3/HjeYdjsNRMRtkGjoLGQqPXVdKM//TSQHB2Sc+oWIcWmscvYJoN19SsgCaWk073mltthdo+zOeuFSGYsUKj7YXOLbTfm'+
 'BJpslQRVM8GQdgv1ufSGKFccVRESkb5RsWjM2MvvzZNtDKPFpICW1Q3Elo3EeP6D9iYNPBMPh4dRcya8e2DnNSDjA24o9xStoN+SCZwwU6Dfq1lAoBMZxrvGCjnKLicLUuckMCAwEAAaOCAoEwggJ'+
 '9MB8GA1UdIwQYMBaAFDAKLAy4Nyvg9toC/oCCZ5aYVBk7MFsGA1UdIARUMFIwUAYGYEwBAgMEMEYwRAYIKwYBBQUHAgEWOGh0dHA6Ly9yZXBvc2l0b3Jpby5zZXJwcm8uZ292LmJyL2RvY3MvZHBj'+
 'YWNzZXJwcm9yZmIucGRmMIHRBgNVHR8EgckwgcYwPKA6oDiGNmh0dHA6Ly9yZXBvc2l0b3Jpby5zZXJwcm8uZ292LmJyL2xjci9hY3NlcnByb3JmYnY0LmNybDA+oDygOoY4aHR0cDovL2NlcnRpZ'+
 'mljYWRvczIuc2VycHJvLmdvdi5ici9sY3IvYWNzZXJwcm9yZmJ2NC5jcmwwRqBEoEKGQGh0dHA6Ly9yZXBvc2l0b3Jpby5pY3BicmFzaWwuZ292LmJyL2xjci9zZXJwcm8vYWNzZXJwcm9yZmJ2NC'+
 '5jcmwwVgYIKwYBBQUHAQEESjBIMEYGCCsGAQUFBzAChjpodHRwOi8vcmVwb3NpdG9yaW8uc2VycHJvLmdvdi5ici9jYWRlaWFzL2Fjc2VycHJvcmZidjQucDdiMIGhBgNVHREEgZkwgZagQAYFYEw'+
 'BAwGgNwQ1MDMxMDE5NzMwMjQ1MjIwNzcxMzExNjUxMTMwNzgxMDAwMDAwNDU3OTc2MDg5REVUUkFORVOgFwYFYEwBAwagDgQMMDExNjUxMTMwNzgxoCcGBWBMAQMFoB4EHDAxNDgxMzEzMTQwNjAw'+
 'MTAxMTFWSVRPUklBRVOBEHJzQHByb2RhZi5jb20uYnIwDgYDVR0PAQH/BAQDAgXgMB0GA1UdJQQWMBQGCCsGAQUFBwMEBggrBgEFBQcDAjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAgEAQoQ1UiFiVuklBLM8U'+
 'lVteQnQNUdAZFoE2BGIsPHJd5nG5lW+RpWadU12EcM10AtFd/eJgfLIR2xU/FEmFhKNok+MA+g+h4RUBHbg8RVvoVSvw3dLGbO9HkaZ3nziwOTKHzq32G0MsQ47g4aoeOt9p9SNZhcUoSXESPgCco'+
 'uJSLW2H2SYp7bBBB1hDivWqqhwgDXY+kGkleKgjWrE4KdhXQXzD0hj9OubG/huOBUyRaD3kAGF2yTxqUS4vl/oRicpO3NyPa0f3ScGkKtLsAJUAfnfv9p5JUEpVR5sFf7RoGXvv6zDoZnG7QKxuUR'+
 'L+x5/ZV2k5dmNSkcmyCwKKnguytRA/S/UZ1NJ3+G3M4g+nNMuofMlFLYPtGGLWQWEY9i32wARLjo6fwcD26NxRxVRYkUOmMe8GSc7gmfqNSC/+FMqMV12EJdvgui6gytLVaXfC1oAjXwkb0e3pQT7'+
 'u0+jZsnfAexAvOCNEfe6Jx9ANOF7KrvOr5Tp33l2lPcGD3PQRMsySUCHb95mu9lZ/lqzEKJjwXJ4z2KCCPQ6Su8FKTgUoYTl2BnTJBBPDw06nLBwqB2EiFWnPr+NF5HEuLDcGTysgoFcll4fPJu3y'+
 '2OMeq6OGR3xOhK2FEJx9efYZ6KKtGVrR4l6IieDK9joskSRYzU+ZERjvHD8dWm1U9+QXjQ=</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature>'+
 '  </eFinanceira>'+
 '  </evento>'+
 '  </loteEventos></eFinanceira>');

 vXmlData := vWsRecepcaoSoap.ReceberLoteEvento(vXmlData);
 Memo2.text := vXmlData.XMLNode.XML;

 end;

procedure TForm7.HTTPRIO1HTTPWebNode1BeforePost(const HTTPReqResp: THTTPReqResp;
Data: Pointer);
var
  Store        : IStore;
  Certs        : ICertificates;
  Cert         : ICertificate2;
  CertContext  : ICertContext;
  PCertContext : PCCERT_CONTEXT;
  V            : OleVariant;
  vCertsLista       : ICertificates2;
begin
  (*
    thumbprint of the certificate to use. Look at CAPICOM docs to see
    how to find certs using other Id's
  *)
 (*
    thumbprint of the certificate to use. Look at CAPICOM docs to see
    how to find certs using other Id's
  *)
  V := 'BC50E0E8CA750D6F7524EC58B3071E9FCB4C8920';

  (* create Certificate store object *)
  Store := CoStore.Create;

  (* open the My Store containing certs with private keys *)
  Store.Open( CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_STORE, 'MY', CAPICOM_STORE_OPEN_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED );

  (* find the certificate with the given thumbprint *)
  vCertsLista       := Store.Certificates as ICertificates2;

  Certs :=  vCertsLista.Find(CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_SHA1_HASH, V, False);

//  Certs := Store.Certificates.Find(CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_SHA1_HASH, V, False );


  (* any certificates found? *)
  if Certs.Count > 0 then
  begin
    (* get the certificate context *)
    Cert := IInterface( Certs.Item[ 1 ] ) as ICertificate2;
    CertContext := Cert as ICertContext;
    CertContext.Get_CertContext( Integer( PCertContext ) );

    (* set the certificate to use for the SSL connection *)
    if InternetSetOption( Data, INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT,
        PCertContext, Sizeof( CERT_CONTEXT ) ) = False then
    begin
       raise Exception.Create('Erro ao configurar certificado para conexão SSL.');
    end;
  end;

end;
```

Please can anyone help me?
Many thanks!

the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
          <eFinanceira xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.eFinanceira.gov.br/schemas/envioLoteEventos/v1_0_1">
            <loteEventos>
              <evento id="ID0">
                <eFinanceira xmlns="http://www.eFinanceira.gov.br/schemas/evtAberturaeFinanceira/v1_0_0">
                  <evtCadDeclarante id="ID00000001762">
                    <ideEvento>
                      <indRetificacao>1</indRetificacao>
                      <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
                      <aplicEmi>2</aplicEmi>
                      <verAplic>00000000000000000707</verAplic>
                    </ideEvento>
                    <ideDeclarante>
                      <cnpjDeclarante>02475222000196</cnpjDeclarante>
                    </ideDeclarante>
                    <infoCadastro>
                      <nome>CECM SERV ESTAT ADM DIRETA EST E SANTO</nome>
                      <enderecoLivre>AV  JOAO BATISTA PARRA  N  673 EDF ENSEADA TOWER LJ 1 PRAIA DO SUA</enderecoLivre>
                      <municipio>3205309</municipio>
                      <UF>ES</UF>
                      <Pais>BR</Pais>
                      <paisResidencia>BR</paisResidencia>
                    </infoCadastro>
                  </evtCadDeclarante>
                  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <SignedInfo>
                      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                      <Reference URI="#ID00000001762">
                        <Transforms>
                          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>G8kSjLVludtkatDuCm2rLszM7D4=</DigestValue>
                      </Reference>
                    </SignedInfo>
                    <SignatureValue>f7OmvLKjuuRQiX+6tgqBYxB5zBFgxjXMyXOqZkWtLhgW2lP/ZzM7xrnt9HZFBSetIhJNGuPhKysZzf4hZClW1YSEfi2WECb3CNzBCfjzeOA2fEJ/FJXdYdDsAvtzjTbtE+MqrJW/u9sGNJHJDTtVfdjPwt3Y9NUJJ0SADvDtXPiow71rcpAeg3fQD3IIFlPLyz0WbGiUyzDcsl3pb7L7AYilj5Pm5utV0COq8A0jwnMylKolGHScXgJaPW3U9qHw9KDeaGP0NfgEYyYTk/C8TNSZXb5AKj2sFr9rfLRuTOqEJHjKvlYmWsGUCTwEVkkNakTYbuNFYsXB++nVVaoD7Q==</SignatureValue>
                    <KeyInfo>
                      <X509Data>
                        <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
                      </X509Data>
                    </KeyInfo>
                  </Signature>
                </eFinanceira>
              </evento>
            </loteEventos>
          </eFinanceira>
        </schema>
      </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: which line of code does throw the exception?

Comment: it does pass the before post event... and ask for password.. on before execute my soap xml its ok too  vXmlData := vWsRecepcaoSoap.ReceberLoteEvento(vXmlData);

Comment: posted  the soap request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the .net server responded with an error: "Server was unable to process request"
So you have to contact the owners of that service

Comment: So, do you think everythig is ok with the coding and the request? Did email the owners waiting for response.

Comment: I've tried the same thing with c# and got an error with more details, and I think this is absolutely a server problem:     System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Serpro.Sped.eFinanceira.WsInternet.Util.MontaXMLRetorno(XElement xelement) at Serpro.Sped.eFinanceira.WsInternet.WsRecepcao.ReceberLoteEvento(XmlDocument loteEventos)